# Limit of $\frac{\sin(xy)}{x}$

Tags: limits, functions

Find limit of $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{x}$$ Is it enough to show that if $(x,y) = \left(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} \right)$ then $lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,0)}n \sin(\frac{1}{n^2})=0$?

Comment: do you mean $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Comment: the limit is zero.

Comment: @RolfHoyer, in either case, the limit is zero.

Comment: no $(x,y) \rightarrow (1,0)$, but my method is correct?

Comment: I guess if it's $(1,0)$ you can just use continuity.  (You shouldn't use a sequence converging to $(0,0)$, though).

Comment: If you know the limit exists, then it is enough (and the same) to compute it along any path.  If you must show that the limit exists, then your method is not enough.  Also, if you let $(x,y)=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$, then $x$ and $y$ are approaching $(0,0)$.  Finally, the last limit should be a limit of $n$ and not of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: what should be done to show that limit exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim the limit is zero.  To show this we have

$\left|\frac{\sin(xy)}{x}-0\right| \le \left|\frac{xy}{x}\right|=|y| < \epsilon$

whenever $0< |y|\le \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} < \delta\le \epsilon$,